# TFS Upgrade 2013 to 2017 WIT not migrated correctly

Tags: tfs

We are in the process of migrating from TFS 2013 to TFS 2017 and for most parts it went really well.

We took a copy of the VM, reinstated it under another server name. I then ran the upgrade over the test server and followed all the prompts, and noted that this was a test machine. So it changes the configs etc, as it needs to.

We then ran into issues. It seems as though it did not upgrade the work item templates properly. Has anyone gone through the migration and had similar issues? Also more importantly how did you solve it.

There are two things that don't quite work. They are the Testing module and reporting. I suspect because there are some work items that are missing.

It appears that the tests were not migrated (although I believe they are in the database). It may just be that they are just not appearing because the WIT are not defined properly.

Can someone please tell me what we can do to migrate the tests across?

[Error that we get when trying to add a new test plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMjX5.png)

Comment: Are you using a stock process template? Did you use the process template upgrade wizard after the installation?

Comment: stock + some additional fields. I didn't even realise there was a process template upgrade wizard. When I try to use the "configure features" then "Verify"  and it goes through inspecting the templates I get a few errors. Here's what it comes up with:

Comment: [Warning] TF400612: The existing work item type 'Test Suite' is reused. If the feature 'Test Plan and Test Suite' is not behaving correctly, you can destroy the existing work item type and rerun feature enablement.

[Warning] TF400607: Category 'Microsoft.HiddenCategory' will be overwritten.

Comment: It was asking for a few WIT's which I have added a few that were missing (so I thought), i'm getting more of these errors and am a bit stuck as far as what is meant to be there. I think if someone can explain how all these WIT stick together would be of great assistance. Then I can go back and see what I need to add/remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are just missing the test plan and test suit. You could go through this topic --  [**Update a team project manually to support test management**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/reference/update-a-team-project-manually-to-support-test-management)

> This topic applies to a team project that is defined on an on-premises
>   Team Foundation Server (TFS)and was created using a process template
>   that doesn't have test plans and test suites work item types.

Comment: This worked. So the process that we had to go through was to first install the templates after we downloaded latest version from the web. At this stage we were then able to create test plans, but we did not see the test plans that we already had in the database. So once we have upgraded the templates, we then migrated the existing test artifacts in TFS. Seems as though tests are now visible and are functioning as intended.